# MVT and functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be defined on an open interval $I := (a,b)$.

(a) Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $x<y$. Show that if $z \in [x,y]$, then there is some $t \in [0,1]$ such that $z=tx+(1-t)y$.

(b) Assume that $f$ satisfies the following conditions:
$$\forall x,y \in (a,b), \forall t \in [0,1], f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \tag{1}$$ (in other words $f$ is **convex**).
Show that for any positive integer m, whenever $x_1,...,x_m$ are in $I$ and $t_1,...,t_m$ are non-negative numbers with $t_1+...+t_m=1$, then,
$f(t_1x_1+...+t_mx_m)\leq t_1f(x_1)+...+t_mf(x_m)$

(c) Suppose  that $f'$ is increasing on $I$. Show that $f$ satisfies (1).

(d) Let $g(x) := ln x$ for $x>0$. Put $f:=-g$. Show that $f'$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$. Hence deduce that if $m \in \mathbb N, x_1,...,x_m$ are positive and $t_1,...,t_m$ are non-negative numbers with $\sum_{k=1}^m t_k=1$, then
$$x_1^{t_1}...x_m^{t_m}\leq t_1x_1+...+t_mx_m. \tag{2}$$

Put $t_k:=1/m$ for all $k=1,...,m$ in (2). What do you obtain?

What I think should be done:

I am not sure what I should be doing for parts (a) and (b). Could anyone help me out please? I think we should apply the MVT here but I am not sure how exactly.

(c) So, I understand that if $x<y$ and $z=tx+(1-t)y$, then we can apply the MVT on $[x,z]$ and $[z,y]$ but I am not sure how to do that to show that $f'$ is increasing.

(d) So, here, $f(x)=-lnx$. So, $f'(x)=-1/x$.
I think we should use the following corollary:
Suppose that $f$ is continuous on [a,b] and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then f is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. That is, if $x_1,x_2$ are in $[a,b]$ and $x_1<x_2$, then $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. 
How can I use this here? Also, From there, how can I deduce the rest of the question?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use the MVT in (a) and (b) because you don't even know that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: (a) is a simple matter of solving the equation for $t$ and noticing that the solution is indeed in $[0,1]$. (b) looks like a clear case for induction on $m$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok. How can I solve (a) and (b)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm So for (a), I got $t=z/(x-y+1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: x @Su003: No, that is not right. Check your algebra and verify each of your steps with some known values (such as $x=10$, $z=12$, $y=13$, $t=1/3$).

Comment: In (c) you're "not sure how to do that to show that $f′$ is increasing" -- but that's not what you're supposed to do! You're _assuming_ that $f'$ is increasing; what you must _show_ is that (1) holds.

Comment: In (d), "hence deduce" means that you should note you have proved that the result of (c) applies to $f$. Now in the equation at the end of (c), insert the definition of your $f$ and take the antilogarithm of each side of the equation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah I made a mistake in (a). Now I got: $t=(z-y)/(x-y)$. And $t$ is indeed in $[0,1]$. 
In (b), how exactly do I apply induction on $m$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, also for (c), should we do something like this:
$f(z)-f(x)/(z-x)$ and $f(x)-f(z)/(x-z)$?

Comment: x @Su003: For (b), when you apply thed induction hypothesis you will do it with some of the $t_i$'s you already have, but _scaled_ such their sum is still 1. (c), yes, that's a good start. Now the MVT together with the fact that $f'$ is increasing will give you an inequality to work with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But does f(z)−f(x)/(z−x) equal $f'(t)$?

Comment: x @Su003: No it doesn't. Do you remember what the MVT claims?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Assume that f is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then, there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $(f(b)-f(a)/(b-a))=f'(c)$.
That's MVT right?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: so should we say there is some $c \in (x,z)$ and some $d \in (z,y)$ such that $f(z)−f(x)/(z−x)=f'(c)$ and $f(y)−f(z)/(y−z)=f'(d)$?

Comment: x @Su003: Yes, and since $f'$ is increasing you have $f'(c)< f'(d)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok, so I did it and I tried to simplify it and I got stuck with something like:
$yf(tx+(1−t)y)-xf(tx+(1−t)y)<xtf(y)+(1-t)yf(y)-xf(y)+yf(x)+xtf(x)+(1-t)yf(x)$. Is this right? How can I simplify further from here?

Comment: x @Su003: At this point the algebra gets too complex for me to keep in my head, so I can't give any precise guidance. But _intuitively_ the inequality you start with here ought to give you what you need. I would suggest working in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$ rather than $x$, $y$ and $t$, so keep $f(z)$ as $f(z)$ and instead plug in your known expression from (a) at the _remaining_ $t$s.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok thanks. Also, we came up with the inequality : $f′(c)<f′(d)$ but we need to show $f(tx+(1−t)y)≤tf(x)+(1−t)f(y)$.How would we get from < to $\leq$?

Comment: x @Su003: Hmm, actually if $f$ is not _strictly_ increasing, you get only $f'(c)\le f'(d)$. But in general, if you can prove $A<B$, then that automatically implies $A\le B$...

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok, thanks. I kept the $z$ when simplifying the inequality and I ended up with: $(y-x)f(z)<zf(y)-xf(y)+xf(z)+yf(x)-zf(x)$. I only need $f(z)$ on one side of the inequality but then I'll have a fraction on the other side. Would that be correct?

Comment: x @Su003: Well if you insert your expression for $t$ in $tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ from (10, you get fractions too, so that would be alright. I'm not convinced about your algebra -- there's an $xf(z)$ left on the right-hand side that ought to be gone by now -- but otherwise it looks reasonable. Good luck with the details.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Alright, thank you I'll figure it out. But could you please enlighten me a little more for (b)? I am still lost.

Comment: Also for (c), I got $f(z)=((z-x)/(y-x))f(y)+((y-z)/(y-x))f(x)$ instead of $f(z)=((x-z)/(x-y))f(y)+((z-y)/(x-y))f(x)$. I can't see my mistake. :/

Comment: x @Su003: Is there a difference? Remember that $a/b=(-a)/(-b)$.

Comment: x @Su003: For (b), here's a hint: $$t_1x_1+\cdots+t_{n+1}x_{n+1} = (t_1+\cdots+t_n)(\frac{t_1}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}x_1+\cdots+\frac{t_n}{t_1+\cdots+t_n}x_n)+t_{n+1}x_{n+1} $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm what would be the base case for it though?

Comment: x @Su003: The $m=2$ case is the same as the assumption (1). And the $m=1$ case is just $f(x_1)\le f(x_1)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm so $x_2$ will be equal to $y$ and $t_2=1-t_1$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Actually I am still confused about the Induction hypothesis. How do we come up with it here? :/